# How to change the audio frequency of a C # MediaElement

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mediaelement

I am currently working on an application Dj for windows 8 metro app . And I would like to know how to allow changing the frequency of a "MediaElement"? The only property to change / vary the parameters are the position / volume / balance. But I wish I could change the frequency in Hertz for example, or to manually set the canal. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaElement.PlaybackRate seems to control playback speed, but not necessarily by affecting frequencies. I believe I have read somewhere that its behavior might depend on specific codec or system and it is most likely not good enough for a Dj application.
I have not tested all these options, but I think alternatives to try are [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee892373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [XAudio2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.ixaudio2sourcevoice.ixaudio2sourcevoice.setfrequencyratio%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though these options are also progressively more complicated.